# set reply arrow via vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I was wondering if there is a way to add the Reply arrow to a selected mail in Outlook via VBA. The background is that we process a selected mail via VBA and create a new mail from it. This does not trigger that the original mail gets a reply arrow. It would be desirable if the mail would still get the arrow.

Code now:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set myItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0

    If myItem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Keine Mail selektiert!", vbExclamation
        GoTo exitproc
    End If
 myItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003", 102
 myItem.Save
```

Comment: How do you process a selected mail in VBA? Do you call the `Reply` method?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: I create a new mailitem and copy some information. I do not want to answer the mail because I have other recipients and other content. But I need the reply-arrow. Cant the flag be set manually on selected item?

Comment: You can set properties in the same way on the item returned from the `Reply` function.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev So you mean i have to use reply and overwrite mailbody and recipients etc?

Comment: If you create a new mail item programmatically, how can `Reply` overwrite anything?

Comment: The Reply method creates a new mail item based on the original source and returns this instance to you. You can do whatever you need to with that item.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: Please see my code. Also with reply i do not get the arrow. Can you edit my code to show me correct way to use reply with my code?

Comment: There is no need to use the following line of code: `Set olNewMailItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)) method if you need to see the reply arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"`) to 102 (which is `EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOSENDER` constant) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`(where `MailItem` comes from the `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection). You might also want to set the `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040"`) to a datetime value.

You will also need to set the `PR_ICON_INDEX` (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003"`) to `261` for the reply icon to become visible.

You can see the property and its values in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author, click the IMessage button).

Comment: Hi, even after wrote:     On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set myItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set myItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0

    If myItem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Keine Mail selektiert!", vbExclamation
        GoTo exitproc
    End If
 myItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003", 102
 myItem.Save the arrow does not exist :-(